# Value of type CharacterSet has no member InvertedSet - Swift 3

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

I am trying to convert over swift 2 code to swift 3:

```
var customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").invertedSet
```

It throws this error:

```
Value of type CharacterSet has no member InvertedSet
```

Comment: "Editor->Convert->To current Swift syntax..." fixes the problem automatically for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1414025-inverted) the name of `invertedSet` method in Swift 3 was changed to just `inverted`. So try this:

```
var customAllowedSet =  CharacterSet(charactersIn:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").inverted
```

**PS:** `init(charactersInString:)` of `CharacterSet` also changed to `init(charactersIn:)`

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 you are also supposed to drop the NS prefix. You should use CharacterSet instead of NSCharacterSet. You should also declare it as a constant.

```
let customAllowedSet =  CharacterSet(charactersIn: "=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").inverted
```

You can also declare it as a static property extending CharacterSet as follow:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    static let customAllowedSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"=\"#%/<>?@\\^`{|}").inverted
}

CharacterSet.customAllowedSet
```

Comment: Actually you can use both `NSCharacterSet` and `CharacterSet`, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset

Comment: I never said he couldn't. I said he should.

Comment: Yes, but without a detailed context where he uses it you can't say "you should"

Comment: Why would you need to use NSCharacterSet?

Comment: :) when you need reference semantics or other Foundation-specific behavior. lol